# Count occurrences of each unique value within a column pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset which looks as follows:

| Station | Month | Year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | Jan | 2021 |
| A | Feb | 2021 |
| A | Jan | 2021 |
| B | Mar | 2021 |
| B | Mar | 2021 |
| C | Apr | 2021 |
| D | Feb | 2021 |

I am looking to write some code which can identify each unique value within a row and tell me how often it occurs.
eg. For the month column the code should tell be Jan occurs twice, Feb occurs twice, Mar occurs twice and Apr occurs once. It would output similar for the Station and Year columns.

My code looks like this at present, but is not working as intended:

import pandas as pd

for col in df["Month"]:
print((df["Month"])[col].unique())

Comment: Read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and [edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) to include one.

Comment: This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `value_counts`
`df["Month"].value_counts()`